# PostgreSQL: how to convert from Unix epoch to "timestamp" until minutes?

Tags: postgresql

How could I convert from Unix to "timestamp" until minutes?

For example,   1672718268 -> 2023-01-03 06:57
upd.: Format - not string

I tried to use function:

- to_timestamp(timemodified)::date + date_trunc('hour', timemodified) + date_part('minute', timemodified)::int
- to_timestamp(to_timestamp(timemodified)::timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
- extract(epoch from timemodified) from table
- date_trunc('minute', to_timestamp(timemodified)::timestamp)

[an example of desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gRBJ.jpg)

Comment: If you want just minutes why not: `select 1672718268 /60; 27878637`? If this is not what you want then you need to provide an example of desired output.

Comment: But I did it.
For example, 1672718268 -> 2023-01-03 06:57
Format not string

Comment: As explained before you can't have that in a `timestamp` type.It will have the seconds portion albeit `:00` as `2023-01-03 06:57:00`. And if you use `timestamptz` then it will have the time zone. Otherwise you will have to have a string format, that is the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT to_char(to_timestamp(1672718268), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI');
```

The result will be a string, not a timestamp because a timestamp also has seconds.

For just the date, cast your timestamp to a date:

```
SELECT cast(to_timestamp(1672718268) as date);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I need format like date. Maybe you know how I can do it?

Comment: @Elena: you mean just the date part? Cast the timestamp to date

Comment: No, not exactly that. Unfortunately, I don't know how this format is called...if it exists :)
I added screen with the desired output
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gRBJ.jpg

Comment: And has been explained, several times, that is not possible with the `timestamp(tz)` data type. You would need to make it a string. See [Output style](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-OUTPUT) for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char(date_trunc('minutes', to_timestamp(1672718268)), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI');
     to_char      
------------------
 2023-01-02 19:57
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need date until minutes . Now it's look like '2023-01-03 06:57:00.000 +0300'

Comment: You are going to have to update your question to show a complete example from input to output of what you want. FYI, a `date` does not have minutes, so you are looking for a `timestamp` and that will have seconds unless as @FrankHeikens pointed out you keep it as a string.

Comment: My comment was for first version of your answer date_trunc('minutes', to_timestamp(1672718268))
I understand about date, but I hope that it's possible to convert timestamp until minutes...but probably not :(
Thank you for help